# Rails Read csv file data with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rails-activestorage

I have this class and I am using active storage

```
class MaterialsUpload < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :csv_file
end
```

This is the attachment

```
#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x007ff1f0be9e90
 @dependent=:purge_later,
 @name="csv_file",
 @record=
  #<MaterialsUpload:0x007ff1f0c604f0
   id: 3,
   success: 0,
   errors_list: [],
   total: 0,
   created_at: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 14:43:35 UTC +00:00,
   updated_at: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 14:43:35 UTC +00:00>>
```

Is there a way I can read the data so I can do something like this

```
string = materials_upload.csv_file.read
CSV.parse(csv_string, headers: true) do |row|
    # do something
end
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`download`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-download) to obtain the file’s contents:

```
CSV.parse(materials_upload.csv_file.download, headers: true) do |row|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks that was what a was looking for !!

Comment: @george-claghorn I need to use `CSV.foreach` instead of `CSV.parse` (because there are too many rows in the file) and `file.download` seems like using too much memory. How can I get a needed file path? (I'm using amazon S3)

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be another option (when it's local on disk). I used code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51709314/3622415) answer

```
file_path = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, materials_upload.csv_file.key)
CSV.foreach file_path, headers: true do
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score -2):

After uploading you can read CSV file into an HTML table with [CSV::Table](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html) lib:

```
def show
  @csv_data = CSV.open('uploaded_file.csv', headers: true).read
end
```

Example for view:

```
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0" >
  <tr>
  <% @csv_data.headers.each do |header| %>
    <th><%= header %></th>
  <% end %> 
  </tr>
  <% @csv_data.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
    <% row.each do |value| %>
      <td><%= value[1] %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

Comment: The problem here is I cannot get the file from active storage