# Where does active storage store files (on disk), and how can I retrieve them physically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am using active storage with Rails 5.2. I am following the EdgeRails guide, and have configured Active-Storage to use the local disk.

The file uploads work great when I am using the Rails App.

However, the problem is that I need to physically access those uploaded files without using Rails as a mediator.

A query for where the files are stored returns this:

```
url_for(@employee_staff.avatar)
=> "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBGUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--e76664d247cb5437fe1cd11f7ee0ded24f95aee2/profilepic3.jpeg"
```

I am trying to figure out where this file path is saved in my local disk. So far, I've had no luck.

Any explanations about how Active-Storage works and where I can see the uploaded files are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the [guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am still confused about which directory active storage is saving files in.
I'm currently using the "Disk Service" option specified in the guide, so I'm expecting that it would be somewhere in my file system.

Comment: Yes, if your storage.yml looks like in the guide, then the files are in your project folder.

Comment: I have been trying to find the /rails/active_storage/ in my project (using vscode find folder feature), still can not see any listing of that particular directory. I've also tried to physically search for it, no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get path to ActiveStorage file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340043/get-path-to-activestorage-file-on-disk)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On your local development machine (since you mentioned local disk), you should have a file `config/storage.yml` that has a block similar to below:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join('storage') %>
```

In this example above, I'm storing the files in a folder named `storage` in the root of my rails application. Inside that folder you'll find nested folders that aren't meant to be navigated via file explorer/Finder (but you can).

Thru your rails app, via views for example, you'd use the [url helpers](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32866#issuecomment-388205649) which aren't well documented yet.

From a rails console, you can try, for a model named `Foo`, with a `has_one_attached :photo`

```
Foo.last.photo.blob.key
```

It should give you a ~24 character string.

- The first 2 characters are a subfolder inside the folder I pointed you to above
- The next 2 characters are a subfolder inside that

Inside the subfolder is a file with the name that matches the key you printed out above (no extension). That's your file.

Comment: So are the files encrypted? Is there any way for me to retrieve the base file without using ruby code?

Comment: No, they're not encrypted. ActiveStorage changes the file name (based on some kind of hash I think) and drops the extension, so you'll see a bunch of files with no extensions in those subfolders. You should be able to open them (on macOS at least), but you might need to change the extension in some instances.

Comment: I tried it and you're right! Is there a way to make it disable this change of file name with new uploads, or map it to its original name?
I am looking at the active storage blobs database table, and it does have a key and checksum for each entry. Does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: If you're going to try and disable the rename, you're probably better off not using active storage (unless I missed something in the docs). I believe it renames the files this way for performance reasons. You have access to the original filename via the blob data as I showed above. You also have the ability to get the file name using the url helpers I linked. If there's a specific problem you're trying to solve I might be able to provide you with guidance on solving it but you'd need to provide more details on what you're trying to do with the original files

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answers, it explains things a lot better. Still not completely sure why Active Storage insists on weird file names, but I guess I will work around that somehow. Answers Accepted.

Comment: One reason it might not use the original filenames is to allow for multiple files with the same name. For example, multiple users might upload a file called profile.png

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.service.path_for(@employee_staff.avatar.key)
```

As seen in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53908358/7573223)

Answer (score 1):

If you have variants:

```rb
variant = @employee_staff
            .avatar
            .attachment
            .variant(resize: '100x100')
            .processed # If variant is not processed

variant.service.send(:path_for, variant.key) # Absolute path to variant file
```