# How do I get the local path to an Active Storage Blob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I built my Rails app and figured I would use Active Storage (AS).  I then realized that AS dumps all your files into your storage root.  I need to segregate that between clients and also I would rather organize these on a model basis etc.  Carrierwave (CW) can do this out of the box.  I am going to build a rake task to migrate these old attachments over.

The AS blob key is the filename stored locally except on my local machine its stored like this:

```
/storage/HR/mw/HRmWZZNk4wd7dD1nt9iUbi1n
```

and on my S3 compatible store:

```
/HRmWZZNk4wd7dD1nt9iUbi1n
```

There seems to be no built-in method to return the local path of an AS file (which CW has).  I know I can on the fly build the local path but looking to see if I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 4):

Found it here:

[Get path to ActiveStorage file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340043/get-path-to-activestorage-file-on-disk)

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, user.avatar.key)
```